# How can I cite one sub-equation in subeqnarray?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I defined the following subeqnarray

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{subeqnarray}
    & a_1+b_1=c_1, \label{eq:subeq1} \\
    & a_2+b_2=c_2, \label{eq:subeq2} \\
    & a_3+b_3=c_3. \label{eq:subeq3}
    \end{subeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

How can I cite one of these equaiton, say subeq2. I used `\ref{eq:subeq2}`, but it gives me only one number with out b. What I want is (eq-number b). Or is there any other method to achieve my aim?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Which package defines the environment `subeqnarray`?

Comment: Hi, @ Mico, I am new to Latex. I just use \usepackage{amsmath} and
 \usepackage{cleveref} in the head of my document. I even don't know which package define this environment. I am sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would *not* use a `subeqnarray` environment. Instead, I would (a) load the [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/) package and (b) nest an `align` environment inside a `subequations` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align" and "subequations" environments and "\eqref" macro
\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this example
\begin{document} 
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    & a_1+b_1=c_1, \label{eq:subeq1} \\
    & a_2+b_2=c_2, \label{eq:subeq2} \\
    & a_3+b_3=c_3. \label{eq:subeq3}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

A cross-reference to equation \eqref{eq:subeq1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Mico, thanks. It is very close to my aim, however, in fact the lengths of my equations are very different with each other, so I want to center them instead of aligning. I have tried to remove your \begin{align} and \end{align} but it does not work.

Comment: @lxy -- if the equations should be centered rather than aligned, just remove the three `&` alignment markers and replace the `align` environment with a `gather` environment.

Comment: @ Mico, cool! :) The problem is terminated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I strongly support **Mico**'s advice in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250802/3954) about switching to one of the environments provided by `amsmath`. However, if you decide to keep the use of `subeqnarray`, you need to use `\slabel` instead of the standard `\label` command to get the proper string in the cross-references:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subeqnarray}

\begin{document} 
Some cross-references to subequations~\ref{eq:subeq1}, \ref{eq:subeq2} and~\ref{eq:subeq3}.
    \begin{subeqnarray}
    & a_1+b_1=c_1, \slabel{eq:subeq1} \\
    & a_2+b_2=c_2, \slabel{eq:subeq2} \\
    & a_3+b_3=c_3. \slabel{eq:subeq3}
    \end{subeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If, additionally, you load `amsmath`, then you can use `\eqref` to automatically get the parentheses surrounding the cross-references, but then again, if you load `amsmath`, switch to one of the environments it provides.